# Using VLANs to pass two separate LANs over a single ethernet run (with a twist)- best practice?

Tags: router, switch, vlan, local-area-network, ethernet

I am using two small managed switches each side of single ethernet run linking two rooms, to 'trunk' two VLANS, enabling two separate LANs to pass over it. The source of the each LAN being it's respective router at each end.

*I will refer to the single ethernet cable linking the two rooms, simply as the 'link.*

With a router each side of this link, i need LAN1-out from one router to reach WAN2-in of the other (across the link).

**My question is, can i enable this router to take the place of one of the managed switches?**

This router, expecting the WAN2-in, is 802.1q VLAN capable.

The other router is not 802.1q capable (i also have no access/control over it as it's third-party managed, and simply only have the aforementioned LAN1-out to play with).

Ultimately, assuming the VLAN setup of one switch is adopted by this router, one of the LAN-outs is going to be feeding straight back into the very same router's WAN2-in. This VLAN will of course be untagged on it's outbound LAN port before reaching WAN2-in.

We are essentially utilising this router's onboard switch to do the VLAN tagging/untagging in place of one of the switches.

This obviously doesn't *seem* good practice, having a cable looping straight back into the router it came from, **but can someone explain any obvious problems with this idea that i may have overlooked?**

There are no issues with me continuing to use both switches either end of the link, but this is purely an out-of-interest/theoretical question at this point.

So to summarise the setup.. two switches each end of a single ethernet 'link', with two VLANs passing over the link. Both VLANs tagged on the link-connected ports, and untagged when leaving the switches on another port.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically I have two rooms and two ADSL lines (1 in each room). These two lines need to feed into a central router which then does policy routing to send traffic out over the appropriate broadband line according to the traffic type. The other 'locked down' router is simply necessary to provide a LAN (this setup is out of my control) which we use to feed into the main router's second WAN. So basically, we're sending this LAN down the Ethernet run connecting the two rooms, and into the main router's WAN. Next we want to send another LAN back up this Ethernet run...

Comment: First you write about two switches (layer-2), but then you refer to routers (layer-3). Layer-3 switches are layer-2 switches with a router module. Router-to-router links should be routed links, not VLANs. VLANs are layer-2 concepts for layer-2 switches. If you have an 802.1q trunk (tag VLANs) on one side, and the other side is not 802.1q capable, it is likely to drop tagged frames

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but is this gigabit ethernet or 100 Mbps? Because if it is 100 Mbps you can use a splitter on both sides to convert the single ethernet 8-wire you seem to have into two ethernet 4-wires -- it seems that could help.

Comment: (continued)   ...to serve hosts back in the original room. This LAN is now subject to policy based routing by the main router. This the whole aim here, the main router doing policy routing for traffic destined for a particular of the two WANs. The complexities simply arise due to the fact that the ADSL lines terminate in completely separate rooms with only a single Ethernet run between the rooms.

Comment: It is not the easiest setup to explain without a diagram (will provide tomorrow) but there is good reason for it. Simply picture then Ethernet link in the middle, the two switches at each end, then the two routers behind those switches. Router 1 sending LAN1 across the link into router 2's WAN2. Then router 2 sending its LAN1 back across the link but only as far as the switch, which will then further serve connected devices.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a router on a stick.

This isn't necessarily wrong, but it's to be avoided in large deployments, as it bottlenecks your inter-vlan routing to a single machine.

In medium to large deployments, using the routing capabilities of a quality managed layer 3/4 switch for inter-vlan routing would be best for performance, as the entire switch can be used for this across any port, rather than just one port. Most managed switches have a "router" function; even the low-end powerconnects have it. In these core-router based configurations, it's still necessary to provide a firewall in most cases, and these routers you're using now would be converted to "border routers".

In your particular case, this current configuration is one that you're going to have to consider growing out of moving on. However, I'm hesitant to give you specifics because I find the wording of your question to be quite confusing. You keep referring to "the router", yet you have two routers that are not identical. To help me write a better answer, could you provide some structured details on this network with explicit identities of the physical entities and traffic flow? A diagram of some sort would do that nicely.